# User.Identity.Name is null when integrating ASP.NET Identity with OWIN auth to Azure AD B2C

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, azure-ad-b2c

I am extending an existing MVC web application which uses ASP.NET Identity for authentication. It uses `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` for getting the username of the currently logged on user.

When I switch to OWIN authentication using the sample code explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi) the `Name` property is null, causing the existing application to throw an error. Is it possible to change the value of `IIdentity.Name` without invalidating the identity?

Comment: Not sure but if you return `Display Name` in your application claims it won't be `null` anymore :)  It won't be the `username` though like you had before.

Answer (score 1):

As described at the bottom of [the referenced tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi), you should access the user claims via the `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` object, such as:

```
// Controllers\HomeController.cs

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Claims()
{
    Claim displayName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().NameClaimType);
    ViewBag.DisplayName = displayName != null ? displayName.Value : string.Empty;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current`